# Is there any way to save space when writing a huge if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say that I have two variables, *x* and *z*, which stand for coordinates.
In my JavaScript code, I'd want something specific to happen for combinations of x/z (up to a thousand).
And since the code will be really long, I'd like to know if there's any way to make this kind of code shorter:

```
if (x == 12 && z == 14) {
  doThis(23);
  alert("doo");
  doThat(661);
}
if (x == 13 && z == 14) {
  doThis(2345);
  alert("dee");
  doThat(166);
}
if (x == 13 && z == 15) {
  doThis(12);
  alert("duu");
  doThat(44);
}
```

...and so on. I know that to make the file smaller & more compact I can remove all spaces and make everything in be in one line - but how do I make it even shorter?

**EDIT:** The doThis() and doThat() are just examples of "code" that would be in there. The code will actually be completely different in all of the if statements. Changed it now.

Comment: Are they the same doThis and doThat ? If so you may create an array of valid (x,y) and iterate on them to see if one of them applies

Comment: Try to refactor your solution maybe? If that's not the case, your best bet is obfuscation & minify solutions then.

Comment: What exactly the combinations you want to check?

Comment: @hindmost Basically a ton of combinations of x/z variables, for each combination there would be unique code (like different alert text be shown, for example). I've been thinking that perhaps you could create functions named like "x12z14()", "x13z14()" and so on, then launch the function as "x<VARIABLE_X_VALUE>z<VARIABLE_Z_VALUE>, that would be more compact than launching a thousand if statements, wouldn't it?

Comment: You could make a data object of combinations, like: `var combinations = {'12&14': [23, 'doo', 661], '13&14': [2345, 'dee', 166] ...}`. Then retrieve the object for parameters, for example: `doThis(combinations[x + '&' + z][0]);`

Comment: I would suggest to create nested (2d) hash mapping each x/z combination to respective data.

Comment: @hindmost That might work as well, but the data in the example in the OP _seems_ to be totally combination-dependent. Not sure, if the real data is.

Comment: @Teemu Perhaps you misunderstood me. I meant the same case. Something like this: var hash = {12: {14: [23, 'doo', 661]}, 13: {14: [2345, 'dee', 166], 15: [12, 'duu', 44]}};

Comment: @hindmost Yes, I misunderstood your previous comment, now I understand what you mean. The data object will be huge with both styles, though. OP: If there are some depedences between coordinates and values, this might be much simpler.

Comment: If you are dealing with a coordinate system, and what appears to be collision detection, it seems like you're approaching this problem incorrectly all-together. You should write a general-purpose collision detection function that computes if any two bodies have collided, and if so, executes some code based upon those two bodies and their parameters.

Comment: @OregonTrail This might be a kind of a game board too, that would explain individual actions on different coordinates. To know for sure, we've to wait for OP's response.

Comment: @hindmost and Teemu, I hope you don't mind me including some of your ideas in the answer I posted.  I wrote the first part under the assumption that the code was *different* for each condition but in case it only differs by parameters, your way is clearly superior so I tacked that part on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values of **x** and **z** determine *completely different code* as you have suggested, then something like this might simplify things.

```js
var work = (function(){
    var _work = {};
    var _getKey = function(x, z){ return x + "~" + z;};
    var _set = function(x, z, fn) { _work[_getKey(x,z)] = fn; }
    var _get = function(x, z) { return _work[_getKey(x,z)] ;}
    return {get : _get, set : _set};
})();

work.set(12, 14, function(){
  // code unique to this combination of x and z
  console.log("doo");
});

work.set(13, 14, function(){
  // code unique to this combination of x and z
  console.log("dee");
});

work.set(13, 15, function(){
  // code unique to this combination of x and z
  console.log("duu");
});

var x = 12;
var z = 14;
work.get(x, z)();
```

On the other hand, if the code is the same, except for parameter values (per your code example), then something like this (as suggested by @Teemu and @hindmost) would be superior

```js
function doThis(param){}
function doThat(param){}

var work = (function(){
    var _work = {};
    var _getKey = function(x, z){ return x + "~" + z;};
    var _set = function(x, z, args) { _work[_getKey(x,z)] = args; }
    var _get = function(x, z) { return _work[_getKey(x,z)] ;}
    return {get : _get, set : _set};
})();

work.set(12, 14, [23, "doo", 666]);
work.set(13, 14, [2345, "dee", 166]);
work.set(13, 15, [12, "duu", 44]);

var x = 12;
var z = 14;
var args = work.get(x, z);

doThis(args[0]);
console.log(args[1]);
doThat(args[2]);
```

Given that **x** and **z** have now been identified as *coordinates*, the note in your original post from @OregonTrail is probably the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Build a json object such that:

"12" has "13" and "14" in it,

"13" has "11" and "12" and "13" in it,

so you check first if z exists in that json object then if x exists in that z object in the json object.

```
zxMap.hasOwnProperty('12')

then if true, get that to another object variable(or an array) and check

foundZ.hasOwnProperty('13')

or

foundZ.includes("13");
```

then this should give true or false

so only 2 "if"s are needed once you build that json object.

```
{
  "12": ["13","14"],
  "13": ["11","12","13"]
}
```

then write two functions to check against z and x values:

```
if(has_x(has_z("12"),"13"))
{
   do_this();do_that();
}
```

if do_this has differencies,

```
{
  "12": {"13":"doo","14":"dee"},
  "13": {"11":"daa","12":"duu","13":"dii"}]
}

if(has_x(has_z("12"),"13"))
{
   do_this();
   alert(extract_message("12","13"));
   do_that(); 
}
```

it could even be a code string in that last element in json object, to be executed as javascript.

```
  eval(extract_message("12","13"));
```